# Having trouble with Bash / Shell While Loop String Comparison

Tags: bash, shell

I'm learning scripting to help with my work, and I'm just trying to wrap my head around using `while` loops.

I want to repeat a question if a user doesn't answer with Yes or No. 
Currently I have that working with an if conditional statement, that was easy, but it simply exits the script if the user doesn't answer with y or n.

I've tried various iterations of the below, figured out that I can't use `-ne` unless it's an integer, but what I can't seem to get right is the string comparison.

I found much better ways to do this online, but it's pointless to copy-paste those if I'm missing something basic about a simple while loop.

```
#!/bin/sh

while [ $CONFIRM != "^y"|"^n"] # This is where I'm stuck
do
echo "Please say Yes or No."   # Probably not doing this right either
read CONFIRM                   # Or this
done

if  echo "$CONFIRM" | grep -iq "^n" ; then
echo "Okay, stopping script."
else

#do some cool stuff

fi
```

Any and all advice appreciated.

---

And the correct answer is...

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nocasematch

while ! [[ $CONFIRM =~ ^(y|n) ]]
do
echo "Please say Yes or No."
read CONFIRM
done

echo "Success!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing regular expressions with pattern matching.

```
# Regular expression
while ! [[ $confirm =~ ^(y|n) ]]; do
```

or

```
# extended pattern
while [[ $confirm != @(y|n)* ]]; do
```

should each do what you want.

---

The `read` command takes the *name* of a variable as its argument.

```
read confirm
```

Using a parameter expansion causes `read` to set the value of the variable whose name is contained in `confirm`:

```
$ confirm=foo
$ read $confirm <<< 3
$ echo "$foo"
3
```

Comment: Thanks, @chepner.  As I'm using `#!/bin/sh` and looking for case-insensitive pattern matching, I should add that to get this to work I changed to #!/bin/bash and added `shopt -s nocasematch` above my while loop.

Comment: Ah, that `read $confirm` was oversight, should have spotted that!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
while [[ -z $confirm || ( $confirm != y && $confirm != n ) ]]; do
 read confirm
done
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, @rigglesbee, thank you! This is really useful.